# Google Cloud Storage for dynamic website using HTTPS

Tags: https, google-cloud-storage

Currently I'm hosting a client application written in AngularJS on Google Cloud Storage using the configuration described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#tip-dynamic).

I like this configuration because it acts as a CDN and we don't have to use a dedicated machine to host the frontend files.

The problem is that Google Cloud doesn't support HTTPS for custom domain names, and we want to improve our security standards serving at least the *login page* on an https domain.

¿Is there anyway we can keep the static files hosted on Google Cloud/some other CDN for fast serving and use an https domain?

**Update**

For anyone interested, we finally migrated all our CDN with HTTPS requirements to Amazon S3 + CloudFront and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Google Cloud Storage does support HTTPS, it does not support HTTPS for custom domain names.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment. I'll edit my question to reflect this info, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've found a solution not connected with your original question, I'm answering in case someone gets here with the same question  like I did.

Google Firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com) is an excellent way to serve websites (and apps) as it is automatically through SSL (https) and Google Edge servers (effectively CDN function). And https *will* work using your own domain name. You can push your site from your local machine (Node.js needed) or from GitHub, Gitlab, etc. using continuous integration/deploy.

There is a generous free trial plan to try it first, then a reasonable monthly rate to pay as you go as your usage grows. [plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)