# Is Azure or Google Cloud natively support to serve content using custom domain over https

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, https, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to serve my cloud storage content using custom domain over https. Currently, I'm using Amazon S3 with CloudFront to deliver the content using custom domain over https. But S3 with CloudFront is costly, So I'm now searching for an alternative.

1. Is Azure or Google Cloud natively support to serve content using custom domain over https. Without using CDN?

Comment: Why don't you want to use CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, google cloud storage only support HTTP. As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https) To serve your content through a custom domain over SSL, set up a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing), use a third-party [Content Delivery Network](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/09/push-google-cloud-origin-content-out-to-users.html) with Cloud Storage, or serve your static website content from [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) instead of Cloud Storage.

I was able to find this [blog](https://blog.kolibri.is/setting-up-a-continuously-deployed-static-website-with-ssl-39670b37b5c6) which might help you on the setup.

With that being said, if you are looking for functionality like this you may also try with [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), as by default, HTTPS connections on your custom domain will automatically be enabled using managed SSL certificates. You can visit this [link](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html) for more details. Also, there is a there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/70801227) submitted to support auto managed SSL with GCLB.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Azure or Google Cloud natively support to serve content using
>   custom domain over https. Without using CDN?

Azure allows you to map a custom domain to your blob storage endpoint. Using this, you can serve the content stored in blob storage using a custom domain. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name

**However please note that this will not work over https. For https, you will need to use Azure CDN.**

Comment: Thanks for your response, That's what I'm exactly looking for, to serve content over https without CDN. Is this feature available in Google Cloud?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with Google Cloud, hence I won't be able to comment if Google has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's needs will be met by using Firebase as mentioned in passing by @KarthickN.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) is a Google product which deploys your own domain name site automatically through SSL (https).  You can first push your site onto one of the remote git repositories and use CI/CD for Firebase to deploy. You don't need to worry about CDN as firebase will use Google's global edge servers. Small usage is free then move onto paid plans as your needs grow [plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273769/google-cloud-storage-for-dynamic-website-using-https/55086649#55086649).